# Manjaro with KDE takes a long time to wake up after sleeping

Tags: boot, kde, manjaro, sleep

I've been a long time user of Cinnamon, which I always thought was super fast, but recently switched to KDE. My experience has been pretty good on all fronts, except that I’ve noticed my laptop takes a long time to wake up after I close the lid (which makes it go to sleep). It takes about 15 seconds, which seems like a long time compared to my previous experience with Cinnamon, where it was pretty instant.

I don't know if it matters, but booting and shutting off also take long. Although the thing that bothers me specifically is the waking up after sleep.

Not sure what’s going on. 'I’m not sure how to interpret it, but here’s a journalctl output. It seemed like a good place to start

```
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::2358:caa7:fb14:e96b on wlp2s0.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::2358:caa7:fb14:e96b.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703672.5721] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703672.5721] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> terminated
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 10.0.0.23.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: Withdrawing address record for 10.0.0.23 on wlp2s0.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703672.5745] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 6E:DC:1A:EB:57:DE (scanning)
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 10.0.0.23.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: New relevant interface wlp2s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: Registering new address record for 10.0.0.23 on wlp2s0.IPv4.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: Withdrawing address record for 10.0.0.23 on wlp2s0.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 10.0.0.23.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703672.5774] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703672.5776] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703672.5792] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to 48:51:C5:D3:12:97 (unmanage)
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kded5[1476]: plasma-nm: Not emitting connection deactivated notification as we're about to suspend
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kded5[1476]: plasma-nm: Network connectivity limited, scheduling notification
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 wpa_supplicant[949]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 wpa_supplicant[949]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:406:376: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:407:130: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:408:130: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:408:393: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:409:130: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:410:129: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:411:129: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:412:129: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:413:129: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:413:379: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:413:631: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 systemd-sleep[41647]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.virtualkeyboard.hunspell: Hunspell dictionary is missing for "en_US" . Search paths ("/usr/share/qt/qtvirtualkeyboard/hunspell", "/usr>
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: QHttpNetworkConnectionPrivate::_q_hostLookupFinished could not de-queue request, failed to report HostNotFoundError
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: file:///usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/lockscreen/MediaControls.qml:94:9: QML Image: Host i.scdn.co not f>
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.259 seconds
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.003 seconds) done.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: Withdrawing address record for 10.0.0.23 on wlp2s0.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703672.5745] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 6E:DC:1A:EB:57:DE (scanning)
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 10.0.0.23.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: New relevant interface wlp2s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: Registering new address record for 10.0.0.23 on wlp2s0.IPv4.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: Withdrawing address record for 10.0.0.23 on wlp2s0.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 10.0.0.23.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703672.5774] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703672.5776] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703672.5792] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to 48:51:C5:D3:12:97 (unmanage)
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kded5[1476]: plasma-nm: Not emitting connection deactivated notification as we're about to suspend
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kded5[1476]: plasma-nm: Network connectivity limited, scheduling notification
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 wpa_supplicant[949]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 wpa_supplicant[949]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:406:376: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:407:130: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:408:130: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:408:393: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:409:130: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:410:129: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:411:129: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:412:129: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:413:129: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:413:379: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.svg: <input>:413:631: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 systemd-sleep[41647]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: qt.virtualkeyboard.hunspell: Hunspell dictionary is missing for "en_US" . Search paths ("/usr/share/qt/qtvirtualkeyboard/hunspell", "/usr>
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: QHttpNetworkConnectionPrivate::_q_hostLookupFinished could not de-queue request, failed to report HostNotFoundError
Sep 26 17:47:52 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: file:///usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/lockscreen/MediaControls.qml:94:9: QML Image: Host i.scdn.co not f>
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.259 seconds
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.003 seconds) done.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: nvme 0000:01:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0008 address=0xca4f4000 flags=0x0000]
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: nvme 0000:01:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0008 address=0xca4f5000 flags=0x0020]
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: pci 0000:00:00.2: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: pci 0000:00:00.2: PCI INT A: no GSI
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: [drm] PTB located at 0x000000F400900000
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: dpm has been disabled
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: [drm] DMUB hardware initialized: version=0x01010019
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: nvme nvme0: 15/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: [drm] VCN decode and encode initialized successfully(under DPG Mode).
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: [drm] JPEG decode initialized successfully.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring kiq_2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 1
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_dec uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 1
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 1
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc1 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 1
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 1
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 systemd-logind[466]: Lid opened.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 rtkit-daemon[1623]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 rtkit-daemon[1623]: Demoting known real-time threads.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 rtkit-daemon[1623]: Successfully demoted thread 2180 of process 2179.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 rtkit-daemon[1623]: Successfully demoted thread 2179 of process 2179.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 rtkit-daemon[1623]: Successfully demoted thread 2181 of process 2178.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 rtkit-daemon[1623]: Successfully demoted thread 2178 of process 2178.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 rtkit-daemon[1623]: Successfully demoted thread 1699 of process 1591.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 rtkit-daemon[1623]: Successfully demoted thread 1695 of process 1591.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 rtkit-daemon[1623]: Successfully demoted thread 1694 of process 1591.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 rtkit-daemon[1623]: Successfully demoted thread 1591 of process 1591.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 rtkit-daemon[1623]: Demoted 8 threads.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj==unconfined msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" >
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1632703996.653:169): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj==unconfined msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" ex>
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 systemd-sleep[41647]: System returned from sleep state.
Sep 26 17:53:16 yoga6 kernel: PM: suspend exit
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 systemd[1]: Finished System Suspend.
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj==unconfined msg='unit=systemd-suspend comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=>
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj==unconfined msg='unit=systemd-suspend comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=?>
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 systemd-logind[466]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1632703997.136:170): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj==unconfined msg='unit=systemd-suspend comm="systemd" exe="/usr/li>
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1632703997.136:171): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj==unconfined msg='unit=systemd-suspend comm="systemd" exe="/usr/li>
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 ModemManager[593]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is resuming
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 kded5[1476]: bluedevil: About to resume
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703997.1421] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703997.1422] device (wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703997.1592] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 36:EB:B8:A7:71:EA (scanning)
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703997.3673] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703997.3678] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703997.4373] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703997.4373] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703997.4376] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlp2s0 created
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703997.4378] manager: (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6)
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703997.4379] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703997.4383] device (wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 26 17:53:17 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632703997.4390] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 26 17:53:19 yoga6 ModemManager[593]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.4/0000:02:00.0': not supported by any plugin
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 audit[42064]: USER_AUTH pid=42064 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:unix_chkpwd acct="tomas" exe="/usr/bin/unix_chkpwd" hostname=? addr=? termina>
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 kernel: audit: type=1100 audit(1632704000.293:172): pid=42064 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:unix_chkpwd acct="tomas" exe="/usr/bin/unix_chkpw>
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: file:///usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/components/VirtualKeyboard.qml:27: TypeError: Cannot read property>
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 kscreenlocker_greet[41597]: file:///usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/components/VirtualKeyboard.qml:45: TypeError: Cannot read property>
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 kwin_x11[1480]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 30073, resource id: 88080449, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 kwin_x11[1480]: kwin_core: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 30088, resource id: 20971572, major code: 129 (SHAPE), minor code: 6 (Input)
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 kwin_x11[1480]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 30089, resource id: 20971572, major code: 2 (ChangeWindowAttributes), minor code: 0
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 wpa_supplicant[949]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=DRIVER type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5860] policy: auto-activating connection 'Beach House - 2G' (7bb2b2fc-29a9-4cf1-8c42-05981d640d9f)
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5866] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'Beach House - 2G' (7bb2b2fc-29a9-4cf1-8c42-05981d640d9f)
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5867] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5870] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5886] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to 48:51:C5:D3:12:97 (preserve)
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5902] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5907] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Beach House - 2G' has security, but secrets are required.
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5908] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5910] sup-iface[6a0649f71010af90,2,wlp2s0]: wps: type pbc start...
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5955] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5959] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5962] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Beach House - 2G' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets nee>
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5910] sup-iface[6a0649f71010af90,2,wlp2s0]: wps: type pbc start...
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5955] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5959] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5962] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Beach House - 2G' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets nee>
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5962] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Beach House - 2G'
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5962] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5962] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5962] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5962] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.5963] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 kded5[1476]: "Object does not exist at path “/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1”"
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 kdeconnectd[1584]: "Object does not exist at path “/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1”"
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 kded5[1476]: plasma-nm: Unhandled active connection state change:  1
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.6391] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Sep 26 17:53:20 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704000.6391] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 wpa_supplicant[949]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 10:0c:6b:50:2b:34 (SSID='Beach House - 2G' freq=5240 MHz)
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 kernel: wlp2s0: authenticate with 10:0c:6b:50:2b:34
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704003.1213] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 kernel: wlp2s0: send auth to 10:0c:6b:50:2b:34 (try 1/3)
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704003.1214] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 wpa_supplicant[949]: wlp2s0: Trying to associate with 10:0c:6b:50:2b:34 (SSID='Beach House - 2G' freq=5240 MHz)
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704003.2512] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704003.2513] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 kernel: wlp2s0: authenticated
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 kernel: wlp2s0: associate with 10:0c:6b:50:2b:34 (try 1/3)
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 kernel: wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 10:0c:6b:50:2b:34 (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=2)
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 wpa_supplicant[949]: wlp2s0: Associated with 10:0c:6b:50:2b:34
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 wpa_supplicant[949]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 kernel: wlp2s0: associated
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 kernel: wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by 10:0c:6b:50:2b:34
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 wpa_supplicant[949]: wlp2s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 10:0c:6b:50:2b:34 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 wpa_supplicant[949]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 10:0c:6b:50:2b:34 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704003.3563] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704003.3563] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "Beach H>
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704003.3564] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> completed
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704003.3567] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 wpa_supplicant[949]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-35 noise=9999 txrate=0
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704003.3580] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::2358:caa7:fb14:e96b.
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: New relevant interface wlp2s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: Registering new address record for fe80::2358:caa7:fb14:e96b on wlp2s0.*.
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 wpa_supplicant[949]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-35 noise=9999 txrate=245000
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 NetworkManager[462]: <info>  [1632704003.4838] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed unknown -> bound, address=10.0.0.23
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 10.0.0.23.
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 dbus-daemon[461]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.4'>
Sep 26 17:53:23 yoga6 avahi-daemon[459]: New relevant interface wlp2s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
```

Any tip is appreciated!

PS.: I’m using a pretty recent piece of hardware (lenovo Yoga 6 with Ryzen 7), and I’ve already tried upgrading to the latest kernel. I’m currently using kernel v5.14.10.

Answer (score -1):

I do have the same issue for a while and also shutting down takes ages and prints a system broadcast message "System is shutting down NOW!"
Would be interested in any tip too!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/417469)